# Употребление слова сметь

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексикография

Доброго времени суток!

Насколько удалось понять, слово "СМЕТЬ" именно в таком виде, без приставки, существует.

Приведите, пжлста, пример в предложении, который на ваш взгляд является приемлемым в современном языке. (мне это сделать не удалось- все режет слух и кажется неуместным в контексте).

"Как ты мог сметь мне перечить"...?

"Как ты позволил себе сметь не перезвонить"..?

"Сметь нужно было раньше"...?

Answer (score 1):

(от Грибоедова) В мои лета не должно сметь своё суждение иметь.

От себя стишок (почему-то ретро вышло):

Как ты посмел? Подумал бы сначала,
Потом решил бы, сметь или не сметь
Смести с той тайны страшной покрывало -
Бояться Бога надо, за отечество радеть.

Ещё хокку:

На полке ананас чужой, но вот дилемма:
Сметь иль не сметь мне съесть его?
Вам проще, ибо вас не беспокоит эта тема.

Answer (score 1):

Очень часто употребляют гневное и категоричное "Не сметь!"

Answer (score 1):

В мои лета не должно *сметь*

Свое суждение иметь.

(Классик)

Вполне современный язык, не Кантемир же какой-нибудь...

Answer (score 0):

Есть ещё такое - "Знать, сметь, мочь, молчать". Это из изотерического...
Сметь - иметь смелость что-то сделать, идти через страх.
Другим словом и не опишешь так точно смысл и посыл.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд сметь - это способность понимать тайный замысел. Пример: сметка, сметливый. А запрещение "не сметь" относится к не посвященному, не имеющему право высказывать то, что он сообразил, не имеющему право действовать сообразно чужим задумкам.

Comment: Не лезть не в свои дела